# What is the curl equivalent to wget -x?

Tags: download, wget, curl

I want to use curl to save multiple files with the same local paths as would be produced by wget -x (ie, cleaned up versions of the full urls).  But I can't find the right option in the curl docs.  Is this possible?

`curl --remote-name` "Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off."

Answer (score 1):

curl [--create-dirs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

man page says :

> When used in conjunction with the -o option, curl will create the
>   necessary local directory hierarchy as needed. This option creates the
>   dirs mentioned with the -o option, nothing else. If the -o file name
>   uses no dir or if the dirs it mentions already exist, no dir will be
>   created.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite do it: wget -x both creates a local directory like this, and gives each file a path that matches their url (as close to 1:1 as possible).  curl --create-dirs only does the first part of this: if a path is given with -o it will create the required directories, but it won't give a path from the url.